# Sorting values from JSON by values in React

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a React form that uses i18 next translations from JSON file in a dropdown. The objects are very simple: one key, one translation, like this (but the file is very long, there are dozens of keys).

JSON:

```
{
"country": "Country",
"big": "Big",
"dog": "Dog",
"integration": "Integration"
}
```

Code that uses data from JSON:

```
  const createField = (parentName: string, item: any) => {
  const field = {
  type: `${item.type}`, 
  name: `${parentName ?? ''}${parentName?.length ? '.' : ''}${item.name}`,
  label: t(`${item.label ?? item.name}`), 
  properties: {
  placeholder: `${item.placeholder ?? ''}`
  } as any,
  };
        
  if (item.type === 'select' ) {
     field.properties = {
       ...field.properties,
       options: [].concat(item.options?).sort((a,b) => 
        t(`${a.value}`) > t(`${b.value}`) ? 1 : -1).map((option: any) => {
           return {
              label: t(`${option.label}`),
              value: option.value
                  };
                }),
            };
        };
 };
```

I want the dropdown to be sorted according to the value alphabetically because in each language the order would be different. Everything I tried sorts the array from this JSON according to the key.

I tried `concat(item.options?)` for sorting but getting errors *"Expression expected"* and *"property doesn't exist"*.
Also tried this solution, but the dropdowns turned from text into random numbers.

```
if (item.type === 'select' ) {
   field.properties = {
    ...field.properties,
  options: Object.entries(item.options)
  .sort(([key1], [key2]) => t(key1).localeCompare(t(key2)))
  .map(([label, value]) => ({
    label: t(label),
    value
  }))
  };
 };
```

Comment: if you want just values need to sort, then you can use `Object.values(obj).sort()`

Comment: And how to add sorting parameters? Is it sorting alphabetically ascending by default?

Comment: [Official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description) is an amazing resource most of the time. Other than this, what have you tried already on your own? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Updated with the piece of code and what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

Assuming that `item.options` is the JSON data you are trying to sort and convert to a list of options, then the issue is that you've appended the entire options object instead of each individual option. The result is an array of length 1. Another issue is that your data is a dictionary of key-value pairs, not an array of objects with `label` and `value` properties.

## Solution

You can use both [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert the object to an array of key-value pairs and back. For the sorting function you want to sort by the key, and since the keys are strings, use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for the string comparison.

```js
const data = {
  country: "Country",
  big: "Big",
  dog: "Dog",
  integration: "Integration"
};

const sortedData = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).sort(([key1], [key2]) => key1.localeCompare(key2))
);

console.log(sortedData);
```

Since you really want an array of shape `[{ label: '...', value: '...' }, ...]` you can use an [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map the array of key-value pairs to an array of objects with the shape you need for mapping in the option values.

```js
const data = {
  country: "Country",
  big: "Big",
  dog: "Dog",
  integration: "Integration"
};

const sortedData = Object.entries(data)
  .sort(([key1], [key2]) => key1.localeCompare(key2))
  .map(([label, value]) => ({
    label,
    value
  }));

console.log(sortedData);
```

For the actual rendering of your options:

```
options: Object.entries(item.options)
  .sort(([key1], [key2]) => t(key1).localeCompare(t(key2)))
  .map(([label, value]) => ({
    label: t(label),
    value
  }))
```

Since it's not very clear which of the key or value of the JSON data is your option label/value you may needs to tweak the above to fit. I can help here if needed.

Comment: You got it right: I am trying to sort the value of item.options and the value for the options I'm getting from the dictionary file, which has key-value pairs. Now the values in dropdown are shown like "Integration/Big/Dog/Country", and my goal is to sort them alphabetically in the UI, I don't care about the order of the JSON itself. And as translations in different languages are different, I want "Big/Country/Dog/Integration" in English and e.g. "Gross/Hund/Integration/Land" in German. That's why I tried to include sorting in the mapping.

Comment: @Stacey I see, so I think I did get it mostly correct then. Like I said though, if you sort by the value, or translate the value, I can help if converting proves difficult. Is your question/issue resolved then?

Comment: I'm still stuck. I understood the principle but not the implementation i.e. cannot fit it in my code.

Comment: @Stacey Oh dang, I thought it would pretty "drag-n-drop" replacement. What isn't fitting?

Comment: I added it as below and all my dropdowns are showing some numbers now.
        if (item.type === 'select' ) {
            const sortedData = Object.entries(data).sort(([key1], [key2]) => key1.localeCompare(key2)).map(([label, value]) => ({label, value}));
            field.properties = {
                ...field.properties,                
               options: Object.entries(item.options).sort(([key1], [key2]) => t(key1).localeCompare(t(key2)))
  .map(([label, value]) => ({
    label: t(label),
    value
  }))
    
            };
         };

Comment: @Stacey It's hard to read unformatted code in comments, can you update your question to include this new snippet. It looks like you are trying to mix a couple of my snippets. I do apologize if it wasn't clear, but I meant for you to only use the third snippet as replacement. The first two were just for building up the logic so you could see how the arrays were built and sorted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235204/discussion-between-stacey-and-drew-reese).

Comment: @Stacey FYI I've been away, but responded in chat.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps:

**sort object by key and result is an array of sorted keys**

```js
const obj={
            "country": "Country",
            "big": "Big",
            "dog": "Dog",
            "integration": "Integration"
            }
            
            const sortedKeys=Object.keys(obj).sort();
            console.log(sortedKeys);
```

**sort object by value and result is an array of sorted values**

```js
 const obj={
            "country": "Country",
            "big": "Big",
            "dog": "Dog",
            "integration": "Integration"
            }
            
            const sortedValues=Object.values(obj).sort();
                console.log(sortedValues)
```

**sort object by value and result is an object**

```js
const obj={
            "country": "Country",
            "big": "Big",
            "dog": "aDog",
            "integration": "Integration"
            }
           
        //for case insensitive use this function
        const sortedByValue=Object.values(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
            return (a.toUpperCase() < b.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : (a.toUpperCase() > b.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : 0;
        })
        
        function getKeyByValue(value) {
          return Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === value);
        }
        
        const sortedObj={};
        sortedByValue.map(value=>{
        const key=getKeyByValue(value)
        sortedObj[key]=value;
        })
        console.log(sortedObj)
```